# Querying the mapped value of provider(interface java.util.Set) before task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' has completed is not support

Tags: android

Querying the mapped value of provider(interface java.util.Set) before task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' has completed is not supported

android app sdk version 30 upgraded to api 31

can you hekp me solve the problem? thanks

Answer (score 5):

To fix this issue, you have to update the com.google.gms:google-services classpath to the latest version in build.gradle(Project)

Check here for reference [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/225833952)

Answer (score 4):

after update this latest version ,it resolved this issue

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue just now, if you are using latest version of SDK probably you are running your device with latest version of API then you need to follow the Updates from google-services to meet all the requirements needed for your SDK by updating to the latest version.

```
buildscript {
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other answer ,Same issue I faced then I update the jdk version but no worked after that I update the grade version in class path then It resolved the issue ..

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
  }
}
```